# Non-translucent UITabBar creates strange grey bar

Tags: swift, swiftui

Using SwiftUI, I have several NavigationViews nested inside a TabBar. The reason for this is that I would like to change the title of each NavigationView to reflect the selected tab, and I can't find another way to do this. Also, it is very important to my client that the background color of the UITabBar be solid white. For this reason I set `UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false`, otherwise it appears grey. However, as soon as I do this, I see a strange grey line above the UITabBar. How can I get rid of this?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    init() {
            
        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {

        NavigationView {
            
            Text("First tab")
                .padding(10)
                .background(Color.white)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("First tab"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
        .tabItem {
            Text("First tab")
        }
            
        NavigationView {
            
            Text("Second tab")
                .padding(10)
                .background(Color.white)
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Second tab"), displayMode: .inline)
        }
        .tabItem {
            Text("Second tab")
        }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Grey bar above TabBar]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
        UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

is a hack (non-documented assumption about TabView internal implementation) that breaks `NavigationView` layout (removes view to which NavigationView has active constraints)

Here are possible workarounds:

1. use only one root `NavigationView`

[image: demo]

```
struct ContentView: View {

    init() {

        UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
    }

    @State private var title = ""
    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {
            TabView {

                Text("First tab")
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .onAppear {
                        self.title = "First tab"
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("First tab")
                }

                Text("Second tab")
                    .padding(10)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .onAppear {
                        self.title = "Second tab"
                    }
                    .tabItem {
                        Text("Second tab")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle(Text(title), displayMode: .inline)
        }
    }
}
```

2. Create custom tab bar (using `HStack` of `Button` views)

Answer (score 6):

As another alternative to the options in Asperi's answer, you can replace these lines of code:

```
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.white
UITabBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false
```

with these:

```
let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
tabBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
UITabBar.appearance().standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
```

It has the same effect, but using `configureWithOpaqueBackground()` instead of setting `isTranslucent` to false preserves the constraints that NavigationView is relying on.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks!