# iOS 15 SwiftUI TabView tab bar appearance doesn't update between views

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

iOS 15 sets the `TabView`'s appearance depending on the loaded view's scroll position. However, this doesn't seem to update between views switched in the tab bar. How can I fix this so that the appearance updates properly?

1. Opening a tabbed view without scrolling content ("no-scrolling view") uses a transparent background for the tab bar.
2. After navigating to a tabbed view with scrolling content ("scrolling view"), a translucent background is used.
3. However, when coming back to the "no-scrolling view", the **translucent background still remains** instead of being replaced with a transparent background.

I did notice that the appearance updates properly when I open the Control Center or App Switcher and come back.

[image: no-scrolling view transparent]
[image: scrolling view translucent]
[image: no-scrolling view translucent]

Reproduction:

```swift
enum Tab {
    case scroll
    case noScroll
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection: Tab = .noScroll
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection) {     
            Text("Should have a transparent tab bar")
                .tabItem{ Label("No-scroll", systemImage: "xmark.circle") }
                .tag(Tab.noScroll)
            
            ScrollView {
                VStack(spacing: 10) {
                    ForEach(0..<100) {_ in
                        Text("Should have a translucent tab bar")
                    }
                }
            }
            .tabItem { Label("Scroll", systemImage: "circle") }
            .tag(Tab.scroll)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @VisalRajapakse added repro, thanks

Comment: Try to pre-set tab bar appearance forcefully according the needs, like in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63702533/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi I still would like to update the appearance between transparent and translucent, but forcefully setting the appearance would prevent that. I'm looking to have the proper appearance, not a custom one.

Comment: Have you fixed it ?

Answer (score 14):

```
.onAppear {
    if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
        let appearance = UITabBarAppearance()
        UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

it's pretty much the same logic as @cole 's answer but here is my solution:

```
.introspectTabBarController(customize: { controller in

            let appearance = controller.tabBar.standardAppearance
            appearance.configureWithDefaultBackground()
            appearance.backgroundColor = .red
            if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
                controller.tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
            } else {
                controller.tabBar.standardAppearance = appearance
            }
        })
```

to use introspectTabBarController [SwiftUI-Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect)

Answer (score 2):

After update to XCode 13 & iOS 15 I also faced some TabView issues with bar background color and items text & icons color for different states. The way I fixed it:

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
   let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
   tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
   tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.selected.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor]
   tabBarAppearance.stackedLayoutAppearance.normal.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor]
   tabBar.standardAppearance = tabBarAppearance
   tabBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
} else {
   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: selectedItemTextColor], for: .selected)
   UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([.foregroundColor: unselectedItemTextColor], for: .normal)
   tabBar.barTintColor = backgroundColor
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69294720/swiftui-tabview-disable-background-transparency), solved by using this for iOS 15

```swift
@available(iOS 15.0, *)
@NSCopying open var scrollEdgeAppearance: UITabBarAppearance?
```

> Describes the appearance attributes for the tabBar to use when an
> observable scroll view is scrolled to the bottom. If not set,
> standardAppearance will be used instead.

```swift
//@available(iOS 15.0, *)
//@NSCopying open var scrollEdgeAppearance: UITabBarAppearance?

let appearance: UITabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
init() {
    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```